# C strings keep overwriting each other

Tags: c, string, merge, overwrite

Right, so I was screwing around with C with the idea of learning the language by doing a small text based RPG game. I followed the steps of how I did the game similarly in Java but with some different workarounds until I got to the issue of getting output of having the first string being partially overwritten by the second string I was inputting. Here's the bit where the issue occurs (I presume).

```
struct character{
char firstname[100];
char lastname[100]; 
 };

int main(){ 
     struct character charname;

char first=charname.firstname[100];
char last=charname.lastname[100];

printf("And what do they call you?(First name)\n");
scanf("%s", &first);


printf("Any other names?(Last name)\n");
scanf("%s", &last);

printf("So you are called ");
printf("%s ", &first);
printf("%s ", &last);

return 0;
}
```

The Output I got was:

> And what do they call you?(First name)
>   Bob
>
> Any other names?(Last name)
>   Dole
>
> So you are called BDole Dole

I am not BDole Dole but Bob Dole!!!

Any ideas?

(Just realised how horrible the code input thing here is)

Comment: `char first=charname.firstname[100];
char last=charname.lastname[100];` You're already out of bounds there.

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
char first=charname.firstname[100];
```

you get character 101 from an array containing 100 characters (remember that array indexes are zero-based). This alone is *undefined behavior*.

You then make it worse by using `&first` getting a pointer not into the array, not even beyond the array, but a pointer to where the local variable `first` is in memory, writing a string to this location will overwrite memory on the stack, and lead to very serious problems.

What you *probably* want is e.g.

```
char *first=charname.firstname;
```

But that isn't even needed, as arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, meaning this is perfectly valid:

```
scanf("%99s", charname.firstname);
```

<sub>Note the `"%99s"` format, which tells `scanf` to not read more than 99 characters, so it won't write beyond the end of the provided buffer.</sub>

Comment: So the best course for me to take is to remove the [100] off the char first=charname.firstname[100]; ?

Comment: What I really want to do is to use C structures and to store user input into the memory in this example here.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
char first=charname.firstname[100];
char last=charname.lastname[100];
```

Probably what you meant to do was create an array[100] of char, like you would in Java with the "new" operator. But C doesn't work that way. The struct definition tells the compiler that a "struct character" has two 100-char strings in it, so when you write

```
struct character charname;
```

the space for both of those strings is reserved. In advance of needing it, on the stack. It's not initialized, but it's there and it belongs to the struct.

So you can populate those arrays now by calling scanf. Notice that no & or [] are required here; the array is said to "decay" into a pointer when used for its value.

```
scanf("%s", charname.first);
/* later... */
scanf("%s", charname.last);
```

However, it is usually smarter to use fgets() -- see [this C FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Aside, it looks like you may be trying to learn C by taking Java-like code and modifying it haphazardly until it compiles. This does not work, especially in C. In some languages, you can get a pretty good idea of what is legal by listening to what the compiler tells you; but C has a comparatively weak type system and so it can't tell when you do something dumb.

Comment: Ah cheers mate. I realised what was going on after looking at the FAQ! Thanks a lot!!!